# I need float hours from given hours,minutes,seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with a task in my course, I have the parameters and examples, I need to create a function that makes the result of it the same as given in the examples. Below is the explanation and the code.
if you can help me I'm very grateful.
thanks.

> First parameter is the number of hours, the second parameter is the time in minutes (between 0 and 59, inclusive), and the third parameter is the time in seconds (between 0 and 59, inclusive).

Return the combined time as a float\verb|float|float value. (Please note: in a1.py\verb|a1.py|a1.py, we have provided the completed docstring for this function, including example function calls with the expected return values.

```
def to_float_hours(hours, minutes, seconds):
""" (int, int, int) -> float

Return the total number of hours in the specified number
of hours, minutes, and seconds.

Precondition: 0 <= minutes < 60  and  0 <= seconds < 60

>>> to_float_hours(0, 15, 0)
0.25
>>> to_float_hours(2, 45, 9)
2.7525
>>> to_float_hours(1, 0, 36)
1.01
"""
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a coding service. What have you tried already?

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Comment: i as tried 
return (hours + minutes + seconds) / 60

but is wrong
and i can think another solution for this

Comment: you can add hours + mins/60 + sec/3600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [converting minutes and seconds into hours](https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Seconds-Into-Hours) you have to divide them by *60* and *3600* respectively.

float_hours=hours+minutes/60+seconds/3600

```
def to_float_hours(hours, minutes, seconds):
     """ (int, int, int) -> float

     Return the total number of hours in the specified number
     of hours, minutes, and seconds.

     Precondition: 0 <= minutes < 60  and  0 <= seconds < 60"""

     return hours+minutes/60+seconds/3600
```

Comment: Please don't do people's homework for them. We don't provide a code writing service and this encourages bad behaviour.

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 2):

As you want the output to be in hours, convert `minutes` to hours and `seconds` to hours. Then add all of them.

- `1 min = 1/60 hr`
- `1 sec = 1/3600 hr`

This one-liner is enough

```
return hours+minutes/60+seconds/3600
```

output

```
>>> to_float_hours(0, 15, 0)
0.25
>>> to_float_hours(2, 45, 9)
2.7525
>>> to_float_hours(1, 0, 36)
1.01
```

I think when you want to handle date, time use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) library.

Comment: Please don't do people's homework for them. We don't provide a code writing service and this encourages bad behaviour.

Comment: @Chris in the comments he told he tried. He tried to return `(hours+minutes+seconds)/60`. So, I posted the answer thinking it would help him recognize his mistake.

Comment: @Ch3steR, fair point. At least you explained your answer, unlike the other user who just gave back a bunch of code to copy and paste. I fixed a small typo and took back my downvote.